# Can I get IIS to treat some .shtml files as .php files?

Tags: html, php, mod-rewrite, iis, server-side-scripting

I want to be able to get IIS to interpret SHTML files (only in a specific directory) as PHP, and interpret the rest as SHTML.

*If so*, then **how**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are [instructions from Microsoft.](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4c840252-fab7-427e-a197-7facb6649106.mspx?mfr=true)